# Regex: group of optional words surrounded by non-alpha catches only one word

Tags: regex

I have some python code doing regex to find some common words in  on scientific papers such as 'CONCLUSIONS' and roman numbers. In the following snipped of text I see a problem:

```
import re
re.findall('\W(CONCLUSIONS|V)\W', '\nV. CONCLUSIONS AND FURTHER STUDY')
#['V', 'CONCLUSIONS']  #fine
re.findall('\W(CONCLUSIONS|V)\W', '\nV.CONCLUSIONS AND FURTHER STUDY')
#['V']   #did not catch 'CONCLUSIONS'
```

I think that is due to the group and the surrounding non-alpha '\W'. How can I catch both 'V' and 'CONCLUSIONS'? Now I am trying to make the last \W non-greedy but I think it does not help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use zero width look-around assertions in your regex instead of `match`:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\W)(CONCLUSIONS|V)(?=\W)', '\nV.CONCLUSIONS AND FURTHER STUDY')
['V', 'CONCLUSIONS']

>>> re.findall(r'(?<=\W)(CONCLUSIONS|V)(?=\W)', '\nV. CONCLUSIONS AND FURTHER STUDY')
['V', 'CONCLUSIONS']
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=\W)` is lookbehind assertion that ensures that we have a non-word character at previous position
- `(?=\W)` is lookahead assertion that ensures that we have a non-word character at next position

Comment: positive lookahead alone be sufficient, ie. `\W(CONCLUSIONS|V)(?=\W)`

Comment: Thanks @AvinashRaj, yes in this case just a lookahead should be sufficient but since use of `\W` is to ensure presence of non-word characters on both sides, lookahead and lookbehind are suitable.

Comment: yep, I agree :-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the `\W`s cannot overlap, so the `.` is "used up" by the first match. You could use lookarounds as anubhava suggested, or you can also use [word boundaries](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) like `\b(CONCLUSIONS|V)\b`. In this situation, I don't think there is any inherent advantage to either solution.

Comment: Just a note that `\b` also matches at line start but `\W` or `(?<=\W)` won't. So a `\b` will match `V` if input is `V.CONCLUSIONS AND` but `\W` won't

Comment: I agree with your explanation of the problem, but \b(CONCLUSIONS|V)\b does not seem to catch any of the two words

Comment: @aless80 make sure you put the regex in a raw string, i.e. `r'\b(CONCLUSIONS|V)\b'`. Otherwise, I believe `\b` gets interpreted as a backspace character.